# Upating a TextBox with a Ajax Response

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I just want to update a textbox with the response of an ajax call. i am getting the response and have assigned it to the textbox using

```
document.getElementById("testPad").value = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
```

its getting updated with the entire response text which happens to be the entire HTML page.

on the server action i am sending the response as this:

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().write(output);
```

Although it sounds trivial, i am facing a hell of time with this, guys please help. TIA.

Comment: It's pretty non-trivial to do Ajax cross platform, so might be better using a framework like jQuery.

Comment: i'm with FilmJ why don't use jquery Ajax i'll put an example for to show u how you can achieve this using JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working by setting the header property

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

It was a trial and error still dont know the exact reason why it worked.

Thanks for all your inputs guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush/close the stream.

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().write(output);
response.getWriter().close();
```

I'd suggest [jQuery.ajax()](http://jquery.com/download/). Download the jQuery.js or just use CDN url.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "serverAction",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#resultText").val(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorDesc) {
                    alert(errorDesc);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="resultText" />
  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Show" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose that you a textbox and a button on button click you have to update your textbox

```
 <input id="txtClicked" type="text" runat="server" />
 <input id="buttClicked" type="button" runat="server" />

  $("#buttClicked").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Dashboard.aspx/GetTreeNodesByText", // that's your server side page and the function
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
  $("#txtClicked").val(data.d); //data.d is the response from the server
  }
  });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the responseText string into a HTML DOM, from which you can easily retrieve the information you want.

This link should get you started:

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Code_snippets%3AHTML_to_DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Code_snippets%3aHTML_to_DOM)